# Prism control Access to modules

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

I have a WPF Prism application with a bunch of different modules and the end users have different roles defined. I am looking for a way where I can load modules based on the user's role?

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to populate the ModuleCatalog based on the UserRoles.
One would do this in the Bootstrapper by overriding:
protected virtual IModuleCatalog GetModuleCatalog();
Another extensibility point are:
protected override void ConfigureContainer();

Dig into the startup sequence of your application and the Bootstrapper,
for other ideas can be found there.